# Different highlighting between foldtext and "the line number on the folded line"?

Tags: vimrc, highlight, folding

Can I control the highlighting of the foldtext separately from the color of the line number on a folded line?

I want the foldtext to be quite visible while keeping my chosen line number color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid this isn't possible. See [`:help fold-colors`](https://vimhelp.org/fold.txt.html#fold-colors):

> The colors of a closed fold are set with the Folded group [hl-Folded](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#hl-Folded).  The
> colors of the fold column are set with the FoldColumn group [hl-FoldColumn](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#hl-FoldColumn).
> Example to set the colors:
>
> ```
> :highlight Folded guibg=grey guifg=blue
> :highlight FoldColumn guibg=darkgrey guifg=white
> ```

The `Folded` group encompasses the line number; no further configuration than the above is available.

There is currently [an open issue requesting a way to achieve what you ask for](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/1828), so the Vim maintainers are aware of the problem.